# How to add dropdown menu on tab / tabset [rmarkdown / bootstrap]

Tags: html, r, twitter-bootstrap, r-markdown, blogdown

Documentation for Bootswatch suggests I can use a dropdown menu from a tab in a tabset:

[image]

How can I achieve this with Rmarkdown? I've tried:

```
# SECTION 1 {.tabset .tabset-fade}

## Section 1.1 

## Section 1.2 {????something here?????}
 ### Section 1.2.1  <<<<<<<<< want this to appear under the dropdown menu
```

Comment: For now, I don't think this can be achieved using just rmarkdown. However, you can produce an HTML document with RMarkdown and then tweak the HTML to achieve a dropdown menu. I've filed a [feature request issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1116) on the RMarkdown github page which goes into more detail.

Comment: For now, you can either tweak the HTML to produce a document or use [the bsselectR package](http://walkerke.github.io/2016/12/rmd-dropdowns/) which unfortunately seems to be in a somewhat-stalled development.

Comment: Thanks for opening the request @BIQS. I did not know I could do that. If you want to add the above as an answer, please do so

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is now available within the development version of **rmarkdown**, which you can install this via `devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")`. To add a dropdown menu, you must add  `.tabset-dropdown` to the class header as follows:

```
---
output: html_document
---

# Heading {.tabset .tabset-dropdown}

## Dropdown 1

## Dropdown 2

## Dropdown 3 

## Dropdown 4
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you Michael, I have a problem with the arrow, do you know how to correct this : https://imgur.com/a/DxJO8xT

Comment: Same problem here!

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 6):

For now, I don't think this can be done using just rmarkdown. However, you can produce an HTML document with a tabset section using rmarkdown and then tweak the HTML to convert the tab set to a dropdown menu. Alternatively, you can use the [bsselectR](http://walkerke.github.io/2016/12/rmd-dropdowns/) package, which is unfortunately still in a somewhat-stalled development.

Below is an example of how you'd make an HTML document with rmarkdown and replace a tab set with a dropdown menu.

First, you'd write your rmarkdown document and then knit it to HTML.

````
---
title: "Tabset Example"
output: html_document
---

# The Tabset Section {.tabset .tabset-fade}

## First Tab
Here is the first tab's content.

## Second Tab
Here is the second tab's content
```
````

[image]

Then, in the resultant HTML file, you'd find this section of HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#first-tab" aria-controls="first-tab">First Tab</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#second-tab" aria-controls="second-tab">Second Tab</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and replace it with this HTML:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
     <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
          Choose a Tab <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class=""><a href="#first-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="first-tab">First Tab</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="#second-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="second-tab">Second Tab</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Which should result in your tab set appearing as a dropdown menu, such as the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and I found this fantastic [link](https://rstudio4edu.github.io/rstudio4edu-book/rmd-dress.html).
Changing the `_site.yml` as follows will help. But make sure `-` are inline, there is a space between `-` and `text` and click `Tab` for the `- text` under the `menu:`

```
name: my-website
output_dir: docs
navbar:
  title: My Website
  left:
  - text: Home
    href: index.html
  - text: Readings
    menu:
    - text: Module 1
      href: readings-module1.html
    - text: Module 2
      href: ./insert_a.pdf
```

[image]