# How do you prevent a tabset dropdown from pushing the content below it in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using RMarkdown to create a html document. I want to use a dropdown tabset, but I would like the dropdown menu to open up over the content of the tab, rather than pushing it down.

A minimal example is this:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

## R Markdown {.tabset .tabset-dropdown}

### Tab A
This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

### Tab B
When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:
```

When I knit that I get a page that looks like this

[Closed dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2jjy.png)

Which looks as I'd expect. But when you click the dropdown menu it pushes the content down rather than opening over it.

[Open dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMwuF.png)

Is there a way to prevent the menu from pushing down the content?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956378/how-to-add-dropdown-menu-on-tab-tabset-rmarkdown-bootstrap

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand that post. I am using the .tabset-dropdown in the accepted answer. The other answer mentions changing some html, but that bit of html appears to be generated by javascript in html document I get out. 

Could you help me understand what I need to change instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a [bug](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1697) that has not been fixed yet.

Elaborating on my comment above: This was a [proposed solution](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1116) to your problem that does not seem to work anymore after an upgrade from Bootstrap 3 to 44.