# Search Menus in R Markdown?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, interactive

Using a loop in R, I generated 100 random datasets and made a plot for each of these 100 datasets:

```
library(ggplot2)

results = list()

for (i in 1:100)

{

my_data_i = data.frame(var_1 = rnorm(100,10,10), var_2 = rnorm(100,10,10))

plot_i = ggplot(my_data_i, aes(x=var_1, y=var_2)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(paste0("graph", i))

results[[i]] = plot_i

}

list2env(setNames(results,paste0("plot",seq(results))),envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

What I am now trying to do, is make a Rmarkdown/flexdashboard that can be saved as an HTML file, and:

- Contains all these plots
- Allows the user to search for these plots (e.g. type in "plot76")

In a previous question ([How to create a dropdown menu in flexdashboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73491512/how-to-create-a-dropdown-menu-in-flexdashboard)) I learned how to do something similar.

But I am still trying to figure out how I can get something like this to work. I would like there to be a single page with a search bar, and you can type in which graph you want to see.

Can someone please help me out with this? Are there any online tutorials that someone could recommend?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: My answer to a recent question of yours answered this, I think. I can see that this question was asked about the same time. If it didn't answer this question, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This is a close solution depending on how much you need the type feature. First in the YAML  specify toc and theme as below. This will create a table of contents and allow the users to click each anchor in the list and it will bring them to the appropriate figure. Second use `knit_expand()` and `knit()` to dynamically create html blocks in your code. I did 5 plots here but it should scale to 100.

````
---
title: "plots"
author: "Michael"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: united
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(glue)
library(knitr)

```



```{r,echo=FALSE, results = 'asis'}


my_data_i = data.frame(var_1 = rnorm(100,10,10), var_2 = rnorm(100,10,10))

out = NULL
out2 = NULL
plot_i = NULL
for (i in 1:5)
{
cat('\n## Plot = ', i, '\n')
plot_i = ggplot(my_data_i, aes(x=var_1, y=var_2)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(paste0("graph", i))

out2 = c(out2, knit_expand(text = "{{print(plot_i)}}" ))

cat('\n')

}


```

`r knit(text = out2)`
````

Comment: @ Mike: Thanks! I copied your code into the R markdown window and ran it ... it does not seem to be working? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is what I got: https://imgur.com/a/EO0jmD0

Comment: could you share a screen shot of the code you tried or put it into the question above?

Comment: it looks like you may have tried to create a dashboard and not an .rmd file I would open an rmarkdown file copy the code above and knit it to html